# How to interpret Magento profiler data?

Tags: magento2, pagespeed, profiler, slow-response

We have recently turned on the Magento 2 profiler to try and track down our performance issues on the site. We can see that the `magento->routers_match` process is taking up a good bit of our load time. Now that we can see which processes are taking too long, what should we do about them? Are there any other resources we can utilize to combat speed/performance issues?

Comment: Use tools like Magento's built-in profiler or external profiling tools like New Relic or Blackfire to identify which code blocks are causing performance issues.

Comment: @Harun, we have New Relic as well, but we are not really sure where to look for problematic code blocks

Comment: Do you have APM Tool?